# How do I print the previously solved letter in python for hangman

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have been trying to complete this hangman game. everything works but it doesn't print the previously guessed letter

this is my original code:

```
import random
themes=['school','animals','fruits']
school=["pencil","rubber","notebook","textbook","lunchbox","mathemathics","science","social_studies","physical excersise","english","scale","compass"]
animals=['panther','bear','python','leopard','sloth','lizard','owl','eagle','hyena','wolf','parrot','falcon','deer','hippo','tiger','giraffe','lion']
fruits=['apple','banana','pineapple','grapes','grapefruit','water melon','strawberry','mango','orange','lemon']
i=random.choice(themes)
#stats 
lives=6
chosen_words=[]
#finding which list it is and then giving the random string from that list 
if i=="school":
  answer=random.choice(school)
while True:
  display=""
  print('theme:'+i)
  print('_ '*len(answer))
  guess=input('Enter your letter')
  if guess in answer:
    for letter in answer:
      if guess in letter:
        display+=guess
      else:
        display+='_ '
    print(display)
```

this is my code after trying to print the previous guessed letters

```
    display=""
answer=random.choice(school)
while True:
  print('theme:'+i)
  print('_ '*len(answer))
  guess=input('Enter your letter')
  chosen_words.append(guess)
  if guess in answer:
    if len(chosen_words)>1:#i did this to avoid list index error
      for letter in answer:
        if chosen_words[n] in letter:
          display+=chosen_words[n]
        else:
          display+='_ '
        if len ==n:
          break
        else:
          n+=1
  print(display)
```

the above one as you can see

Comment: your edited code seems to miss something, there is no `n` for `chosen_words[n]` and what is `len` in `if len == n:`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot see previous letters is because you are printing display outside while loop and u are not printing anything in while.(just updating)
try storing previous letter separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost ok but you just need to put display back in while loop and change an if statement

```
answer = 'pencil'
chosen_words = []
while True:
    # put display in while loop to clear the previous display for each loop, 
    # otherwise previous display will be appended at the end,
    # e.g. input e, display = '_ e_ _ _ _ ', then input i, display = '_ e_ _ _ _ _ e_ _ i_ '
    display = ''
    print('theme: school')
    print('_ ' * len(answer))
    guess = input('Enter your letter')
    chosen_words.append(guess)
    # if guess in answer: 
    # (This can be removed as the if statement in for-loop already check if guess in answer)
    # if len(chosen_words)>1: 
    # (No need to check length of chosen_words as we are going to use the whole list)
    for letter in answer:
        # check if letters in answer are already chosen, print all the chosen letters
        if letter in chosen_words:
            display += letter
        else:
            display += '_ '
       
    print(display)
```

Besides, following the style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) can increase readability of your code.

> use 4 spaces per indentaion level

> Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment (=), augmented assignment (+=, -= etc.), comparisons (==, <, >, !=, <>, <=, >=, in, not in, is, is not), Booleans (and, or, not).